# Play button follow cursor in a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have found this codepen https://codepen.io/plankton/pen/aGejYq working good as expected.

I have an element that follows the cursor. But I don't know how limit it to a div and when the cursor goes in this div, this element goes smoothly to the cursor. If I leave from the div, just the element returns to his spot. Just like in the video in this web https://obys.agency/

If It can be done with JavaScript alone it's ok for me.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;
  var xp = 0,
    yp = 0;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX - 30;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 30;
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    xp += ((mouseX - xp) / 6);
    yp += ((mouseY - yp) / 6);
    $("#circle").css({
      left: xp + 'px',
      top: yp + 'px'
    });
  }, 20);

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
```

Comment: $('#YourDiv").mousemove

Comment: @epascarello Thx! I am trying `$('.hola').mouseleave(function(e){
    mouseX = 30;
    mouseY = 30; 
  });` when the mouse leave. How can I control the speed of the element going to x30 y30 when mouse leaves?

Comment: Actually i get it thx for all @epascarello

Comment: I dont know why, but the transition in css when the mouse leaves is not smooth

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  const constraint = document.getElementById('constraint');
  const circle = document.getElementById('circle');

  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
  var xp = 0, yp = 0;
   
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
     if (e.target === constraint || (e.target === circle && e.pageX >= 0 && e.pageX <= 300 && e.pageY >= 0 && e.pageY <= 300)) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - 30;
        mouseY = e.pageY - 30;
     } else {
        mouseX = 0;
        mouseY = 0;
     }
  });

  setInterval(function(){
     xp += ((mouseX - xp)/6);
     yp += ((mouseY - yp)/6);
     $("#circle").css({left: xp +'px', top: yp +'px'});
  }, 20);

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900);
body, html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%; 
    width : 100%;  
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px; 
    border-radius: 50%;  
}

.constraint {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="constraint" class="constraint">
  <span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Its cool, but why if i go so slow, the circle keep in cursor outside the div?

Comment: @Jose, that was a minor glitch, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Oh thx! Beautiful! Can i change 300 for 100% constrait?

Comment: Sure, you can do that